# DRF's CurrentUserDefault isn't returning a user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `ModelSerializer`. I was trying to set a user foreign key when saving a model, instantiated via the `create()` and `update()` methods of a `ModelViewSet` class. Eg:

ModelViewSet:

```
def create(self, request):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=isinstance(request.data, list))
    if not serializer.is_valid():
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Serializer

```
def process_foreign_keys(self, validated_data):
    """ Simplified for SO example """
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, fk_user=CurrentUserDefault())
    validated_data['profile'] = profile
    return validated_data

def create(self, validated_data):
    """ Create a Product instance. Routed from POST via DRF's serializer """
    validated_data = self.process_foreign_keys(validated_data)
    return Product.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

That code doesn't work - it throws an exception on the `get_object_or_404` line:

> int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'CurrentUserDefault'

If I put a few debugging statements in the `ModelSerializer.create()` method, I get weird stuff:

```
currentuser = CurrentUserDefault()

# Expect <class django.contrib.auth.models.User>, get <class 'rest_framework.fields.CurrentUserDefault'>
print("currentuser type " + str(type(currentuser)))

# Causes AttributeError: 'CurrentUserDefault' object has no attribute 'user' 
print("currentuser is " + str(currentuser.__call__()))

# Causes AttributeError: 'ProductSerializer' object has no attribute 'request'
print("currentuser is " + str(self.request.user))
```

All this was done while a user was logged in, so it's not an `AnonymousUser` problem.

What am I screwing up? How do I get the current user in a `serializer` instantiated within the `create`/`update` methods of a `ModelViewSet` via `self.get_serializer()`?

**Edit:** Attempting with a `HiddenField` doesn't seem to work either. From the docs :

> "`HiddenField: This field will be present in validated_data but will not be used in the serializer output representation.`"

So I set as a `ModelSerializer` class field:

```
currentuser = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
```

... and then attempt `validated_data.get('currentuser')` in the `update` method, and that returns `None`.

Comment: Can you post the profile model

Comment: can you try `get_object_or_404(Profile, fk_user=self.request.user)` this

Answer (score 1):

`CurrentUserDefault` is not a magic method that gets the user out of the void. It has to be within the context of a field a shown in the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault)

As @pramod pointed out, you need to either:

```
get_object_or_404(Profile, fk_user=self.request.user)
```

or set a `CurrentUserDefault` as a default value for a field.

Comment: I get `'ProductSerializer' object has no attribute 'request'` from trying to access it in the serializer. I take it `get_serializer` doesn't pass the request context upon instantiation then, and I can only do this processing of the user foreign key in the `ModelViewSet`?

Comment: Updated again based on your answer. With a `HiddenField` the user still appears to be `None`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def create(self, request):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=isinstance(request.data, list), context={"request": request})
```

can you change you `serializer` instantiation to above code and use it as below:

```
profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, fk_user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: context in get_serializer call shouldn't be required as it's already created within the DRF's get_serializer. However, you'll want to change the self.request into self.context['request'], didn't realize that it was in the serializer.

Comment: yeah, completely agree. `context={"request": request}` this way am doing the same thing as change the self.request into self.context['c']. `get_serializer` will have acccess to `self.context['request']` object

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful!